# Raspbian - Run Python script in venv with sudo rights

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am having trouble writing files to a usb drive in /media/usb via python file.write().
How do I run the python script with sudo ? And, since it should be automatic, how would i avoid to type in the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nothing about python script, but linux user permissions.

You can have the following options (choose one),

- Give your current user the access right to the mounted folder of usb drive
- Run script with `sudo` to elevate user privilige

To avoid password prompt, you can add a sudoers file under `/etc/sudoers.d/`, e.g.

```
echo "$USER ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/$USER
```